# What tool do I need to remove this bottom bracket?

Tags: bottom-bracket

Would I need a three-notched tool to remove this?

[image: My Bottom Bracket]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three-hooked spanner is not necessary, but it would improve the engagement and decrease chance of stripping a notch on the BB lockring. [Parktool makes the  HCW-5 spanner](https://www.parktool.com/product/crank-and-bottom-bracket-wrench-hcw-5?category=Crank%20%26%20Bottom%20Bracket), which combines both a three-hook and a single hook. Here's a relevant quote:

> One side is a single hook, the other is a hook spanner with 3 notches
>   for better engagement in the lockrings.

Answer (score 6):

There's two parts to this - the circular lockring around the outside and the cup.

I'm a bad and lazy mechanic and I use a pair of sliding lockjaw adjustable pliers to remove the lockring (assuming its not just hand-tight in the first place). 
This tends to marr the outer edge of the lockring, but on an old beater bike that's not important.
 You can use a rag to protect the finish from the jaws.   The hooked tools never work very well in my personal experience, but YMMV

[image]

I've also used a hammer and drift on particularly stubborn ones, as well as gentle heat from a propane torch.  Once I used an automatic center punch to shock-loose a lockring cos it was the only tool available at the time.

---

To remove the cup you can use a 12" adjustable spanner, but the flats are really small and the tool slips easily.  The proper tool is something like a https://www.parktool.com/product/adjustable-cup-wrench-hcw-11

[image]

Sometimes you can undo the cup and the lockring just comes with it.   Also note the left cup is generally normal-threadded (ie RTLL)

Comment: I highly recommend that Park Tool cup wrench.  Got one of them for our shop, where previously a large adjustable wrench was used, and things got a lot easier (and the language got significantly cleaner).  (For the lock ring it's whatever works -- usually a poorly fitting hooked spanner, but hammer and screwdriver in a pinch.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks I ended up making a rough bushing that uses some huge washers to hold the tool on the flats using the bottom bracket axle.  This let me use more hands for gently persuading it with a hammer.   I've also thought about using a large dowel to round the hand grip, but its too short and will interfere with the other end.  Long term I should get a second, and cut the ends off, then make a longer one like the lezyne pedal spanners with wooden handles.   Leverage for the win !